# In Calendar overlay "Export to Excel" showing blank

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, export

Export to Excel not showing any data for Calendar Overlays Page. How can i fix that?

Comment: can you provide more details ?

Answer (score 1):

The overlays you added are not actually added to your calendar as events but are just presented in the same view. When you choose to export your list to Excel it will only include items from the current list that are visible in your current view. Items shown from other calendars will not be included as these are not items in your list.

Comment: Is there any way that i can change the code behind of this button(export excel) and modify the Viewguid, so that i can fetch records from original list.

Comment: If you have multiple overlays showing in the same view it would be better, easier for you and understandable for the users, to provide per overlay a export link. Export is build like this: /sites/yoursitehere/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Using=_layouts/15/query.iqy&List=%7B10DD3FA6%2D03DD%2D4706%2D96B7%2D9C9CC9A86605%7D&View=%7BF3761C25%2DF895%2D47E4%2DB51C%2DCD5BF106DC02%7D. It contains the List GUID and view guids. You can find the guids by navigating to the view you want to export and click on "Modify view" in the list ribbon.

Comment: is there any way that i can hide the export to excel button on  the ribbon so that user don't click it.

Comment: @suleyman- can you explain in more detail how to get the export to look at other views?