# how to export overlay calendar to excel?

Tags: development, sharepoint-calendar, overlay, sharepoint-ootb

Probably my post is a duplicate of this ([post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181317/in-calendar-overlay-export-to-excel-showing-blank)), but I would still like to pose this question again: How can I export overlay calendar to excel? Current functionality will export it as blank.

It only exports per calendar, not as overlay. I know that I can export them one by one and join all of them into one, but that is not the intention. What is the best possible way to do that? How can I do that programmatically?

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The Calendars Overlay function can only be used to create a special view to see your own schedule and the group schedule from other calendars at the same time, not the content.

Per my research,we could not export the whole calendar overlay view to a Excel via code,it’s by design.

As a workaround,export multiply calendars into separate Excels, then combine the Excels files.

Comment: I know that I can export them one by one, but that is not the intention. I would like to have then all in one.